# Configure PhpStorm to show Issues/Tasks from GitLab

Tags: configuration, task, phpstorm, gitlab

I have a trouble to set up a GitLab's account to manage the tasks (issues) inside the PhpStorm from `TOOLS` > `TASKS & CONTEXTS` > `CONFIGURE SERVERS`

What is a TOKEN field ? Where do I find it, I've searched in my Profile on GitLab server but found nothing.

[image]

Only thing I have found and tried, is a Personal Access Tokens located here: https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens

PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN was already generated and used but it does not work.

[image]

**=== UPDATED ===**

Error log (I have replaced a real URL path with asterixes because of the privacy)

```
2017-09-25 19:59:41,023 [7154630]   WARN - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Cannot connect to GitlabRepository(URL='https://gitlab.com/***/***/issues') 
com.intellij.tasks.impl.RequestFailedException: Request failed with HTTP error: 404 Not Found.
    at com.intellij.tasks.impl.RequestFailedException.forStatusCode(RequestFailedException.java:16)
    at com.intellij.tasks.impl.httpclient.TaskResponseUtil$GsonMultipleObjectsDeserializer.handleResponse(TaskResponseUtil.java:173)
    at com.intellij.tasks.impl.httpclient.TaskResponseUtil$GsonMultipleObjectsDeserializer.handleResponse(TaskResponseUtil.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:222)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:139)
    at com.intellij.tasks.gitlab.GitlabRepository.fetchProjects(GitlabRepository.java:139)
    at com.intellij.tasks.gitlab.GitlabRepository.ensureProjectsDiscovered(GitlabRepository.java:254)
    at com.intellij.tasks.gitlab.GitlabRepository.fetchIssues(GitlabRepository.java:160)
    at com.intellij.tasks.gitlab.GitlabRepository.getIssues(GitlabRepository.java:107)
    at com.intellij.tasks.TaskRepository.getIssues(TaskRepository.java:168)
    at com.intellij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl.a(TaskManagerImpl.java:783)
    at com.intellij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl.b(TaskManagerImpl.java:742)
    at com.intellij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl.a(TaskManagerImpl.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:342)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Reproduce the issue and check Help > Show Log in ... > idea.log file for any particular error messages. Is there anything?

Comment: @VladLuchansky - I've updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I gather, if you generated the token correctly on the Gitlab side (`SETTINGS` > `ACCESS TOKENS` > `CREATE PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN`) and inserted it into the token field at `TOOLS` > `TASKS & CONTEXTS` > `CONFIGURE SERVERS` in PhPStorm, it could be a timeout problem.

If you go to `SETTINGS`(Ctrl+Alt+S) > `TASKS` and change the `CONNECTION TIMEOUT` parameter to, say, `20000ms` it should work.

[image]

[image]

Please refer to this [post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000063484/comments/115000079964) if you have any doubts.

Comment: What is a final SERVER URL in field above where you put your token ?
is it a direct URL of your project (where you see your source code) or it's an `/issues` URL where you see a list of all your issues ?

Comment: That's it! Thank you, @pierrebonbon, I've typed an URL of my project (gitlab.com/name/repo) instead. It should be gitlab.com

Comment: Note: it should be a secure connection, meaning that you need to pay attention to insert `https` as in the image above and not just `http` as I mistakenly suggested in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new Personal Access Token here https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens
and put it in that field.

Have you checked this:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Integration+with+an+Issue+Tracking+System+in+PhpStorm

Comment: That's what I did, but it does not working, so I am out of ideas. 
Personal Access Token was the one which make sense but it's not working.

Comment: do you get any errors? if yes, what does they say? Could you try to increase timeout to 15000 Preferences > Tools > Tasks

Comment: Problem was with URL, it should be a domain name without any additional sub pages.