# PhpStorm / WebStorm, Tasks and GitLab Issues

Tags: gitlab, task, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

It's easy to setup GitLab issues in PhpStorm or WebStorm (description see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400650/configure-phpstorm-to-show-issues-tasks-from-gitlab))

But I wonder about some questions in working with it.

### Change Status in GitLab

If I open an Issue to work on it (Tools ⇒ Tasks & Content ⇒ Open Task ⇒ choose one from the listed ones), where can I change the Status of this task in GitLab?
I mean something like `in Progress`, `done` ...

In a youtube-video - which told how to connect to jira - I've seen something like an Status-Field you can set for the ticket... but I don't found something like this for my GitLab connection?!
[image]

### Connect Issue with new branch

If I create a new Branch from task, it recommend something like:
#252-my-GitLab-Issue-description (then I push it to gitlab)
But if I open GitLab in my browser, I don't see this new created branch automatically assignd with the related issue. (Shouldn't this be the case?)

Comment: These are not configuration issues but rather missing features, so it makes sense to report them to the JetBrains' issue tracker instead https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab Issues don't rely on a "status" field like you'd see in other projects. For Gitlab Issues the only status is "open" or "closed". Otherwise, you can use Labels to track your project-specific statuses, and you can use Issue Boards that are based on your Labels to move issues from one status to another.

[Here's](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/boards/1387466) one of Gitlab's Issue Boards that they use to develop Gitlab itself. Each column in the board is a label on the Issue.

Here's a super-zoomed-out screenshot of that board, with most of the columns collapsed to show an example of what you can do with the Labels and Boards
[image: Gitlab Issue Board]

Comment: But there is no way to move an issue to another Label-Section?

Comment: For issues that are part of an Issue Board, you can drag-and-drop Issues between all the columns. Moving an Issue out of one column and into another will remove the previous Label and add the new Label automatically.

Comment: I know the GitLab - GUI way to do it. The initial question is about to handle this in phpstorm

Comment: Ah ok. I'm not aware of any IDE with that kind of support, but it might be possible one day via extensions (or feature request) since the Gitlab API supports it.